# Does this spawn multiple processes

Tags: terminal, shell

I would like to know if this shell script line spawns multiple processes:

```
nohup openocd -f board/stm32f4discovery.cfg >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null &
other operations here
```

Basically, I want to open openocd which is a server of sorts, and then perform operations on that server etc.

It works great, but I am not sure if it spawns multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways this could result in multiple processes:

1. The `openocd` command is run several times - each will create a new background process unless designed to avoid it.
2. The `openocd` daemon itself spawns lots of processes, because it is designed to

The command you have above will not spawn lots of processes by itself.

Your best bet is just to check the results of `ps auwxf` and see what happens.